# SSRS filter report dynamically clicking on label

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have report in crystal which I am converting in SSRS, there are group labels and sub groups having details. When Click on any country, report refreshes and shows only that country, when click on any city, only that city and country it belong to displayed. How can I do this in SSRS. Sample image is below.

[image]

Thanks

QF

Comment: look into subreports, you can pass parameters from your main report into the subreports to achieve what you want. If there is not much data you could also collapse groups and have them expanding when you click your country/city of whatever.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But in crystal it looks user in same report every time clicks on city or country, reports gets refresh and comes with filtered data. Any idea?

Comment: You can't do this in SSRS unless you have everything in a single report and then collapse expand groups of data. You can only change the data in a report by running the report again with different parameters. You can create an action to get the report to execute itself but it does reload the report again and it will be noticeable to users.